# Value drawn from a distribution $P(z\mid x)$ and conditional expectation

Tags: probability, distributions, sampling, conditional-probability, expected-value

How would you explain in layman terms the meaning of the statement " $\hat{x}$ drawn from a conditional distribution $p(\hat{x}|x)$ " ? Secondly does $\mathbb{E}_{p(\hat{x}|x)}[\hat{x}]$ mean the conditional expectation of $p(\hat{x}|x)$? In any case it would be helpful if someone could explain $\mathbb{E}_{p(\hat{x}|x)}[\hat{x}]$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\hat{x}$ is drawn from $p(\hat{x} \mid x)$ if it's drawn from a distribution that depends on $x$. Maybe it's mean is a function of $x$, maybe some parameter depends on $x$, maybe both, etc.

You could also write $\mathbb{E}_{p(\hat{x}|x)}[\hat{x}] = \mathbb{E}[\hat{x} \mid x]$. That's probably clearer. If you're dealing with continuous random variables, it equals $\int \hat{x} p(\hat{x} \mid x) d\hat{x}$. So it's a function of $x$. If you're dealing with discrete random variables, it equals $\sum_{\hat{x}} \hat{x} p(\hat{x} \mid x)$, which is still a function of $x$.

Expectations are just weighted averages, only this time we're using weights that depend on $x$. In the continuous case, the weights are $p(\hat{x} \mid x) d\hat{x}$ where $p(\hat{x} \mid x)$ is a density. And if we're looking at a discrete variable, the weights are $p(\hat{x} \mid x)$, where $p(\hat{x} \mid x)$ is a probability mass function.

Answer (score 0):

The conditional expectation gives you what you would expect to be an estimate $\hat{x}$ for some quantity measured by a random variable X, given that the "true" value of X would be x.

Let's say I'm flipping a coin and X can either be 0 or 1 (modeling tails or heads respectively), then the expectation conditioned on e.g. (x=1) would give me an average value I would estimate for x, given that coin flipped heads. Of course, this value could be different from 0 or 1, e.g. 0.5 if I would expect the estimator to randomly choose between the two predictions when the coin flipped heads.

Comment: You can't call two different things by the same name.

Comment: I'm not sure to what exactly you're referring to, but I'll try to answer. A random variable is a function from the experimental outcomes (sample space) to the real numbers, $$X: \Omega \mapsto \mathbb R$$ In this case, $X=1$ and $X=0$ would be two different "names". Also notice, that I could freely map two different outcomes to the same number, e.g. if I would consider coin landing on the edge as well, and map both heads and edge to 1. As long as $X$ doesn't map a single outcome to more than one number everything is fine (otherwise it wouldn't be a function).

Comment: I mean $E[X \mid X] = X$. OP is asking about the conditional expectation of an rv given a different (as far as I can tell) rv.

Comment: At least by convention, $\hat{x}$ is an estimate of $X$, and an estimate and the "real thing" are not the same, and neither am I calling them with the same name.

Comment: Sorry for the previous answer though, I've mistaken you for the OP.

Comment: well you edited it so now it's better, so thank you. However it's still a bit confusing. Now it sounds like you're evaluating an estimator given that you already have the true quantity.